# Long delay between ProgressDialog.dismiss() and AlertDialog.show()

Tags: android, optimization, progressdialog

I'm using a standard `ProgressDialog` implementation: I set up a thread to run a long task, and when it's done it dismisses the ProgressDialog.

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle bundle ) {

        super.onCreate( bundle );

        context = this;
        progress = ProgressDialog.show( this, "Running", "Please wait..", true, false);
        progress.setOnDismissListener( new OnDismissListener() {

            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

                showResults();
            }

        });

        new DeleteThread().start();
}
```

And the Thread looks like this:

```
private class DeleteThread extends Thread {

    public DeleteThread() {}

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // long process during which we populate
        // a LinearLayout with many other Views 
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And in `showResults()` we take the LinearLayout now filled with Views and set it as the content of an AlertDialog.

The problem is, the ProgressDialog goes away and there's still a long period of time (10-12sec) where nothing is happening before the AlertDialog pops up. Is there a way to make this transition instantaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer might be coming in a bit late, but what the heck.

I see that you're triggering the showResults() method from the onDismiss callback. I would suggest you do it the other way around. To do that you may need to use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.

The AsyncTask allows you to easily setup tasks to run in a spawned thread, to update a progress bar if needed (not required, but might be a nice touch in your case) and of course to run some code on the UI thread once the spawned thread completes. For your case, I would place your populating of layoutview in the AsyncTask.doInBackground() method. Then, you'd want to add the showResults() method call in AsyncTask.onPostExecute(). At the bottom of onPostExecute() you should then dismiss your progress dialog. That SHOULD give you the results you want.

As a bonus, you might want to create a constructor for your AsyncTask class and place the creation of the ProgressDialog in there. That way the ProgressDialog will be completely encapsulated within that class and everything is nice and clean. So, something like this:

```
class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncClass
{
  ProgressDialog m_progress;

  public MyAsyncClass()
  {
    m_progress = ProgressDialog.show( this, "Running", "Please wait..", true, false);
  }

  protected Long doInBackground(Object... data) {
    // Do your long process of populating a LinearLayout with many other Views 
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
    showResults();
    m_progress.dismiss();
  }
}
```

NOTE: Above needs some extra parameters to the class, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture a guess as a novice Android developer and suggest that while the pointers are generated for the LinearLayout, the layout itself hasn't been populated with content and therefor is populating when you call progress.dismiss()

You will probably have to render the view prior to setting to the AlertDialogs content.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html might have some help in that respect, unfortunately my laptop is have HDD issues so I don't have the Android Development Environment installed and can't try it. But I'd try an invalidate on the LinearLayout right before progress.dismiss(), I hope that helps :S

Comment: No luck.. I tried `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` as well as `forceLayout()`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of something like this below and use an AsyncTask that dismisses the dialog once it is done:

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());

progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMessage(v.getContext().getText(R.string.defaultQuantities));
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.setMax(100);

new CountDownTimer(250, 250) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        if (progressDialog.getProgress() < 100) {
        progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
}.start();
```